# Class implements a property in a interface who type is of another interface. from below code how should I set values for `Property2`, `Property3`

Tags: c#, interface

N namespace has 2 interfaces IA and IB. one of the properties in IA returns of type IB

```
namespace N    
    {
        Interface IA
        {
            // Have a property Property1 which returns of type IB(interface type)
            IB Property1 { get; } 
        }

        interface IB
        {
            int Property2 { get; }
            int Property3 { get; }        
        }
    }
```

N2 is another namespace in which class A implements IA. my code in this class has to  return the value of  Propert1 of type IB. should my class implement IB also

```
   using N;
            namespace N2
            {
                class A : IA
                {
                    IB property1;
                    IB Property1 { get { return property1; } }
                }
            }
```

Comment: i want to know how to implement the Property1 in the class. How will the user who tries to get the value of Property1 will get the values of Property2, Property3. where should we impleement BI and the properties of B1

Comment: This all depends upon whether you want `A` controlling the property values, the implementation of `BI` controlling the property values, or whatever provides the implementation of `BI` to `A` controlling the property values. Let us know which so we can have more idea as to what you're after.

Comment: Also, your interface naming convention goes against Microsoft's, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bc1fexb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for the interface naming convention. It should be of the form `ISomething`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a setter to the implementation, even if the interface doesn't specify it:

```
class A : AI
{
    BI property1;
    BI Propert1 { 
      get { return property1; } 
      set { property1 = value; }
    }
}
```

or

```
class A : AI
{
    BI Propert1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: no i cannot add the setter to the class, because the AI is public and only my class should be setting the values. the user of my class has access to the interface,and user should not be given chance to set values rather user should only read the value

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your BI interface and then you can use that class for Property1.

```
using N;
namespace N2
{
    class A : AI
    {
        BI property1;
        BI Property1 { get { return property1; } }

        public A() 
        {
            property1 = new B();
        }
    }

    class B : BI
    {
        int Property2 { get { return 2; } }
        int Property3 { get { return 3; } }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a implementation of `BI`.

```
using N; 
namespace N2 {     
    class A : AI     
    {         

         BI Property1 
         { 
              get 
              { 
                   return new B(){Property1 = 5,Property2=100 };
              } 
         }     
    } 


    class B : BI
    {
         int Property1 {get;set;}
         int Property2 {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: u mean to change the BI to have setter also? but user should only read the values of properties in AI and BI but not et them, only my class should set values on the properties in AI and BI

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to use interface `AI` to return the values returned by the properties in interface `BI`, then I think you need to re-think your design. I say this because it is bad practice (in most cases) to have one object provide access to members of another object directly, instead of simply providing access to the other object.

However, given your code example, it does not look like you are trying to do this (I'm a little confused by the combination of question and example). If you are just wondering how to set the values returned by the interface properties, then you need to either provide some setter function, or initialize through the class constructor.

**Setter Property**

Change the properties to be:
    int Property2 { get; set; }

**Setter Method**

Add a setter method to the interface or class:
    public void SetProperty2(int value) { }

**Constructor**

Add a constructor to the class that implements the interface `BI` (presumably `B`):

```
public class B : BI
{
    private int mProperty2;

    public B(int property2)
    {
        mProperty2 = property2;
    }

    public int Property2
    {
        get { return mProperty2; }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think this approach helps me. The interface is given to me and i should build up my class on tht. I cannot do anything to the interface other than wrinting my implementation to use the interface

Comment: @starz26 Please accept an answer and vote up any answers you found useful.

Comment: this is having a problem. when i test Class A from test app, i see that the Class B is instanted twice each time when i read Property1.Property2  and Property1.Property2

Comment: @starz26 Can you edit your original question to reflect this issue and explain it in more detail?